# Python split string by start and end characters

Tags: python, string, list

Say you have a string like this: `"(hello) (yes) (yo diddly)"`.

You want a list like this: `["hello", "yes", "yo diddly"]`

How would you do this with Python?

Comment: The question isn't very clear. What are the criteria for choosing a position to split? Are you looking for the strings inside the parentheses? Fixed locations? Can you rely on the space always being there? If so, will there only be one space, always?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
"(hello) (yes) (yo diddly)"[1:-1].split(") (")
```

First, we cut off the first and last characters (since they should be removed anyway). Next, we split the resulting string using ") (" as the delimiter, giving the desired list.

Comment: I've got to wait 6 minutes, just hold on ;)

Comment: The answer using regular expressions is more flexible. This answer would not produce the correct output e.g. if the string started or ended with a space, or if there was more than one space or a tab character between the parentheses.

Comment: Very true. I purposefully avoided regular expressions in this answer because I thought a solution could be achieved through simpler means. Of course, the OP can use them if he requires further flexibility like you mentioned.

Answer (score 12):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\(([^)]*)\)')
```

The pattern matches the parentheses in your string (`\(...\)`) and these need to be escaped.
Then it defines a subgroup (`(...)`) - these parentheses are part of the regex-syntax.
The subgroup matches all characters except a right parenthesis (`[^)]*`)

```
s = "(hello) (yes) (yo diddly)"
pattern.findall(s)
```

gives

```
['hello', 'yes', 'yo diddly']
```

**UPDATE:**
It is probably better to use `[^)]+` instead of `[^)]*`. The latter would also match an empty string.

Using the non-greedy modifiers, as DSM suggested, makes the pattern probably better to read: `pattern = re.compile(r'\((.+?)\)')`

Comment: Does this have advantages over using `?`?

Comment: @DSM I don't know - but probably its clearer to use the non-greedy syntax. I'll update my answer this way

Answer (score 4):

This will give you words from any string :

```
>>> s="(hello) (yes) (yo diddly)"
>>> import re
>>> words = re.findall(r'\((.*?\))',s)
>>> words
['hello', 'yes', 'yo diddly']
```

as D.S.M said.

`?` in the regex to make it non-greedy.

Comment: I think he would want "yo diddly" as one entry in the array.

Comment: @DSM you dont need the inner pair of parenthesis.

Comment: @vivek: but if you don't use them, then you get left with parentheses.  Compare your output to the desired output.